# Set image in Application title and right align

Tags: android, android-titlebar

How can i set right align **image on title bar** throughout application

I want to image in title bar like below image.

[image]

Comment: What have you tdone uptill ?

Comment: i set <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"       
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  in androidmanifest.xml but it shows the image at left align with application name in title bar.

Comment: AFAIK You can not change the position of the logo of your application. Its fixed based on the android layout design standards.

Comment: which layout i used to get image at right align.

Comment: You can create a common header layout for all the screens of your application and add that layout using `<Include>` Layout.

Comment: can you give me a example. I've never used include in any layout

Comment: Check out http://javatechig.com/android/android-include-tag-layout-example/

Comment: It's really helpful for me. Thank you so much. thanks GrlsHu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [How to use Include Layout?](http://javatechig.com/android/android-include-tag-layout-example/)